# Setting values in JSON to default JSON items

Tags: javascript, json

I am on a Dojo app, is there any special JS parser which enables me default values within JSON data ?

Example, I'd like to set "maxHeadingLength" in item[1] to the value in item[0].

```
   {
    items:[
    {
        "class": "pmedia.types.PMPlatformRenderConfiguration",
        "listItemHeight": "70",
        "listItemIconHeight": "60",
        "maxDesktopItemsWithBannerP": "9",
        "maxDesktopItemsWithBannerL": "9",
        "platform": "Default",
        "maxHeadingLength":
        {
            P:300,
            L:400               
        }
      },
      {
        "class": "pmedia.types.PMPlatformRenderConfiguration",
        "listItemHeight": "70",
        "listItemIconHeight": "60",
        "platform": "IPAD",
        "maxHeadingLength": "Default"
      },
```

Something like this would good too :

"maxHeadingLength": "this.items[0].maxHeadingLength"

Thanks

Update, It seems I can and need to precise  the question a bit better now.

I'd like to write any string expression into the pure JSON string data(file), as string of course and evaluate the data within the same data set without using "eval". 
Thanks to all !

Comment: Are you talking about JSON that is still a string, or the resulting object once the JSON is parsed, or an object literal in your JavaScript?

Comment: yes, this data need to be first in a file and loadable with dojo's xhr from a local file or remote server. I'd like to pass this data via url parameter eventually later to override some settings. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can either do this in a backend process or using a front end process as you process the JSON.

Let's assume you're wanting to do it in the front end using JS, I would suggest firstly setting the `items[0].maxHeadingLength` as a var, like so:

```
var defaultMaxHeadingLength = items[0].maxHeadingLength;
```

And then as you loop through your JSON you can check whether the `maxHeadingLength` attribute has a value or not and default it, like so:

```
var item, i;

for ( i = 0; i < items.length; i++ )
{
    item    = items[ i ];

    item.maxHeadingLength   = item.maxHeadingLength ? item.maxHeadingLength : defaultMaxHeadingLength;
}
```

Comment: This way needs quite some overhead. I expect many default values in nested structures, so ideally I'd like to define in an item's value like this here : maxHeadingLength="Platform:Default". Its looks, I need to write an own little parser which allows me read/write ops from a self defined syntax. I just hoped, there is something out-of-box like XML schemas. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea of one way to do it (if I understand what you're trying to do):

```
var defaultItem = {
    "maxHeadingLength": {
        P: 300,
        L: 400
    }
};

var jsondata = {
    items: [
        {
        "class": "pmedia.types.PMPlatformRenderConfiguration",
        "listItemHeight": "70",
        "listItemIconHeight": "60",
        "platform": "IPAD",
        "maxHeadingLength": this.defaultItem.maxHeadingLength
        }
    ]
};


alert(jsondata.items[0].maxHeadingLength.L);
//returns 400
```

Basically you have a default item separate to all your other items, allowing you to refer to the defaults in the main data.

I don't think you can use this.jsondata from within the same object, since it hasn't finished being created yet (but I could be wrong).

Comment: as explained in the first answer, the defaults are stored within a file. I need a sort of parser which makes a looksup  in the same file and replaces the value from a specified item. thanks